# ATMega328P ADCSRA register issue

Tags: arduino, cpu-registers, atmega, adc, atmelstudio

I want to set up the ADC0 channel of my Arduino in Microchip Studio and I run into a strange issue. I want to initialize all the bits in the ADCSRA register except ADIF. I do so by calling an init-Function in my main, which is defined in a external source file. I tried a couple of methods for writing the bits, the outcome always being the same, so let's say I did it pretty bland like this

`ADCSRA = 0xEF;`

No matter the way I write these bits, when I debug this step, the value in the register is shown as -81 in the Autos Window, and the Hex-Wert in the Data Register as 0xAF. However, 0xEF is written into register 0x18, which is reserved for system purpose, according to the data sheet.

One step before all of this, I set the ADMUX register with `ADMUX |= (1 << ADLAR);`, which works just fine.

I have no idea what's going on here. If anyone could lead me to the solution, that'd be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: `0xAF` is `0xEF - 0x40`. That's the ADSC bit. Check the datasheet for that bit.

Comment: But why does it not get set? The only thing I find is that the first conversion will take longer than usual, but the bit should read 1 as long as the conversion is in progress, right?

Answer (score 0):

When you write `0xEF` to `ADCSRA`, one of the bits you are setting to 1 is named ADSC.  This is the bit in position 6, so it has a corresponding bitmask of `(1 << 6)` which is `0x40`.  The ADSC bit is a special bit because it triggers the ADC to start a conversion.  When the conversion is finished, the hardware clears the bit.  You didn't say what kind of debugging or simulation tool you are using to look at the `ADCSRA` register, but perhaps it is a tool that allows your ADC to run at full speed even if the CPU is paused, so the conversion would finish in a matter of microseconds, and `ADSC` would be 0 before you can see it being 1.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I'm using the "on board" Simulator from Microchip Studio, if that's of any help.